# Make a Query in MS Access default to landscape when printed

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, printing

How can I programmatically make a query in MS Access default to landscape when printed, specifically when viewing it as a PivotChart? I'm currently attempting this in MS Access 2003, but would like to see a solution for any version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function should do the trick:

```
Function SetLandscape()
   Application.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
End Function
```

Should be able to call this from the autoexec function to ensure it always runs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ahockley's call sets the application's printer orientation to landscape.  I tried an experiment and it worked well.  I know this doesn't produce a pivot table, but I didn't setup one to use, so it opens and prints a regular query.

```
Private sub
    Application.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry1", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll
End Sub
```

If you want to close the query after printing it, add:

```
docmd.Close acQuery, "qry1", acSaveNo
```